# Does anyone know how to download the Three.js converted file using Autodesk View and Data API?

Tags: viewer, autodesk

I am trying to use the WEBGL(three.js) file translated through REST api using Autodesk view and Data API.
But, I am not able to download the streaming JSON file, does any one knows about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only a specific mesh, you may try as described here: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/05/viewer-api-search-dwg-solids-by-layer.html and check the following line (that gets the three.js mesh)

```
var mesh = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(viewer, fragIdsArray[0]);
```

And you check  this sample for a full download: http://extract.autodesk.io/